# Zoom doesn't work on map with KML layer

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map with KML layers on it with 3 countries - http://learn.javascript.ru/play/XfYicc

Everything works perfect except zooming - any value I enter - nothing change, e.g.:

```
zoom: 11,
```

If I remove KML all works perfect.

Any chance for me to reduce current  zoom with KML layer on?

Comment: [**`preserveViewport:true`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps myoptions will not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389093/google-maps-myoptions-will-not-work/22390295#22390295)

Comment: Dr. Molle, thanks a lot for your help - all works perfect and sorry for duplicate.