# The Google Maps JavaScript API is not zooming when I change the default zoom setting

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

The zoom is set to 8 and I am using a KmlLayer for a radius. No matter what I change the zoom setting to the zoom level stays the same on the website: http://mainelyknowleslobster.com/delivery/.

```
    <script>

    function initAutocomplete() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        //center: {lat: 28.53687, lng: -81.38328},
        center: {lat: 28.5893244, lng: -81.3744571},
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });


    //Add marker and popup info
    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          '</div>'+
          '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">MAINEly Knowles Lobster</h4>'+
          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
          '<p><center>887 Jackson Ave<br> Winter Park, FL 32789<br> Phone: <a href="tel:407-960-7441">407-960-7441</a><br> <a href="/contact/">Contact Us!</a></center></p>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</div>';


      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: 28.5893244, lng: -81.3744571},
        map: map,
        title: 'MAINEly Knowles Lobster'
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

      // Polygon 
      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://mainelyknowleslobster.com/map/circle.kml',
        map: map
      });

      var markers = [];
      // [START region_getplaces]
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          // Create a marker for each place.
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          }));

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
      // [END region_getplaces]
    }

    </script>
```

I read somewhere that it might have something to do with the perspective of the viewport. I added the preserveViewport property but this did not solve the problem. I wonder if the KML layer has anything to do with it:

```
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
     preserveViewport: true
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps myoptions will not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389093/google-maps-myoptions-will-not-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API 3 - zoom not honored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696589/google-maps-api-3-zoom-not-honored)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `preserveViewport: true` for the KmlLayer

```
// Polygon 
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://mainelyknowleslobster.com/map/circle.kml',
  preserveViewport: true,
  map: map
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwr0qpvw/)