# google map api v3 and kml = zoom doesn't work

Tags: google-maps-api-3, zooming, kml

So, I have html file with google map api v3 and another kml file together connected. If i disconnect kml from html zoom is working.

Here is a sample:
http:/mini.hr/test.php

And here is sa sample of html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">  
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=******&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.330963,14.44046);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    //add KML
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://***/***.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

    //var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://***/***.kml',
    //{suppressInfoWindows: true});
    //nyLayer.setMap(map);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And here is kml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Folder>
    <name>Moja mjesta</name>
    <Style>
        <ListStyle>
            <listItemType>check</listItemType>
            <ItemIcon>
                <state>open</state>
                <href>:/mysavedplaces_open.png</href>
            </ItemIcon>
            <ItemIcon>
                <state>closed</state>
                <href>:/mysavedplaces_closed.png</href>
            </ItemIcon>
            <bgColor>00ffffff</bgColor>
            <maxSnippetLines>2</maxSnippetLines>
        </ListStyle>
    </Style>
    <Document>
        <name>Legend</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Style id="Style10">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>7fffffff</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>66938ab5</color>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id="Style11">
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#Style10</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#Style1</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
        <Style id="Style1">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>7fffffff</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>66938ab5</color>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="Style12">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>7fffffff</color>
                <width>0.2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>66938ab5</color>
                <outline>0</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="Style100">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>7fffffff</color>
                <width>0.2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>66938ab5</color>
                <outline>0</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id="Style110">
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#Style100</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#Style12</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
        <Folder>
            <name>MJESNI_ODBORI</name>
            <open>1</open>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Zamet</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Sveti Nikola</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Mlaka</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Potok</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Turnić</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Podmurvice</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Banderovo</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Škurinjska Draga</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Kantrida</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Grbci</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Srdoči</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Gornji Zamet</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Pehlin</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Škurinje</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Drenova</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Luka</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Pećine</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Krimeja</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Vojak</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Podvežica</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Gornja Vežica</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Brajda-Dolac</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Belveder</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Školjić</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Centar-Sušak</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Bulevard</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Kozala</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Grad Trsat</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Orehovica</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Draga</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Sveti Kuzam</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Brašćine-Pulac</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Pašac</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ****
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Svilno</name>
                <styleUrl>#Style11</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
                                ***
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
        </Folder>
        </kml>
```

Hope somebody can figure where is my problem of zooming :) tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps zoom gets overriden, when using a kml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187837/google-maps-zoom-gets-overriden-when-using-a-kml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the [**`preserveViewport`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#KmlLayerOptions)-option of both KML-layers to `true`