# Geolocation service failed on Mobile with google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using the following script on my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);
      var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=210000746142049190989.0004ce14b7a8e95167602");
    kmlLayer.setMap(map);

      // Try HTML5 geolocation
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                           position.coords.longitude);

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
          });
           map.setZoom(14);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
          handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
      }
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
      if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
      }

      var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: errorFlag
      };

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
      map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
```

I am also using the following which is needed for mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

But still when I visit the site on mobile, and I click to view the map I get the error "The Geolocation service failed."

Is there somthing else I am missing for the geo-location to work on mobile?

You can see the site and live example [here](http://www.drinkrumble.com/mobilemap.html) on the site, right hand side if you scroll down just past the fold you will see "where can I get rumble?" click on that for the map.

**EDIT** I think it has somthing to do with the kmlLayer it seems to be defaulting to that on mobile?

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=210000746142049190989.0004ce14b7a8e95167602");
kmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Maps zoom gets overridden, when using a kml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187837/google-maps-zoom-gets-overriden-when-using-a-kml-file)

in the function initialize, replace all you have before `// Try HTML5 geolocation` with:

```
var mapOptions = { 
    zoom: 8, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions); 
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=210000746142049190989.0004ce14b7a8e95167602", { map: map, preserveViewport: true });
```

Comment: One thing I can't manage to get working is the icon size. Apparently this is whats needed but Im having issues implementing it with the KML layer? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3

And here is your jsfiddle if it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1412/