# Google map throws error when adding 'preserveViewport:true' to kmlLayer options

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google map started throwing 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null ' error when I added `preserveViewport:true` to the kmlLayer options based on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187837/google-maps-zoom-gets-overriden-when-using-a-kml-file).

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/svp70tjx/1/

html:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 11,
                center: google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207),
                styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":-10},{"lightness":30}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":-60},{"lightness":10}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":-60},{"lightness":60}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":60}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":60}]}],
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
                'https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=209537462410499505635.0004d278fb32588bd6da3&ie=UTF8&t=h&ll=48.985492,18.191269&spn=0.27644,0.427604&output=kml',
                {
                    suppressInfoWindows: true,
                    map: map,
                    preserveViewport: true
                }
            );
            ctaLayer.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, the map stopped using the center from the KML and went to the mapOptions where it's

```
center: google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207),
```

had to change it to

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207),
```